# UTF-16 encoding spring mvc and mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, unicode, utf-16, ucs2

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

1)How can i enable UTF-16 encoding in spring filter
I need to take UTF-16 or UCS2 character from a text box in JSP to Spring Controller and insert into Mysql.

2)How can I insert UTF-16 data into mysql

I am configuring JDBC URL like

```
"?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

my column schema is

```
`utf16` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf16 COLLATE utf16_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
```

Answer (score -2):

I see no reason to use `CHARACTER SET utf16` or `ucs2`.  What is your rationale for such?

`CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` is the standard going forward.  It corresponds to the `UTF-8` outside MySQL, as mentioned in `"?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"`

If you really need `CHARACTER SET utf16` *in the table*, then it should work as presented.  MySQL converts from the specified client encoding to the specified column charset.  Yes, utf16 and utf8 are different encodings.

Comment: 'I see no reason to use CHARACTER SET utf16 or ucs2' - sometimes you had to work with what you have

Comment: @msangel - Declare the _client_ to be using such a charset, but declare the _columns_ to be utf8.

Comment: terrifying fact: some legacy databases do not support UTF8

Comment: according to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#History the ucs2 was developed in the late 1980th(originally named "unicode"), while utf16 and utf8 in the late 1990th, so almost 10 years difference

Comment: @msangel - But you don't have to keep using ucs2.  As you migrate to a modern database, convert to utf8.  MySQL makes that easy by letting you specify that the _input_ is encoded ucs2 and the _dataset_ is encoded utf8.

Comment: This database is like terabytes of important historical data, too many services depend on it, and even if migration to a more modern one is a good idea, doing this requires big time and money for a company. As a programmer making such decision is not my responsibility. I only have a requirement - store some data to some database.  And I just have to deal with that fact that this database is legacy.

Comment: @msangel - I guess I am lost -- Are you trying to _read_ the data?  _Update_ the data?  _Add_ to the dataset?  Or what?

Comment: I need to insert data to legacy database, and that database throws an exception if text fields codepoints are out of ucs2 range. ucs2 has a limit in 65k codepoints.  utf-16 has 1112k codepoints. ucs2 is not a utf-16.

Comment: @msangel - Can you provide a specific character that illustrates the problem.  Maybe I can find a workaround.

Comment: workaround already found there:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64862893/transform-utf8-string-to-ucs-2-with-replace-invalid-characters-in-java

Comment: That link shows the need for `utf8mb4` in MySQL; `utf8` will not suffice.  Was the real problem about ucs2?  Or about Emoji?